# Talend - Running a child job if fileName contains given pattern

Tags: talend

What is the appropriate syntax to run a given child job based on the name of a file? My job looks like this:

> ```
> tWaitForFile ---iterate-> tFileCopy ---ifFileNameContains123-> tRunJob1
>                                     \
>                                      \ifFileNameContains456-> tRunJob2
> ```

Is it best to use a regular expression on the RunIf trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this I'd be inclined to put a tMap after the tFileCopy and have two outputs from it. Then open the expression panel on each of the output tables and enter `input_row.FileName.toLowerCase().contains("123")` and connect this output to your tRunJob1 and then `input_row.FileName.toLowerCase().contains("456")` to your tRunJob2.

This makes it quite scaleable to change to more outputs easily and explicitly states that you are looking for file names containing "123" in your first child job and file names containing "456" in your second run job.

Using the expression in RunIf triggers should be fine but as I said I tend to prefer explicitly splitting my flows with a tMap which leaves you with more options later on (plus it allows built in testing right in the component).

Comment: What would the tMap look like? So far there is no input going to it.